# Xcode build error with intercom plugin on Ionic/Cordova app

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, intercom

I'm running into an XCode build error when trying to build my app on a simulator/device.

```
cordova-plugin-intercom 7.1.1
cordova 9.0.0
cordova-ios 5.0.0
cocoapods 1.7.5
```

I initially did not have `cocoapods` installed and ran into an issue with dependencies but was resolved once I installed `cocoapods`.

I've tried different versions of the plugin.

I'm getting

> library not found for -lPods-Bixby

**Bixby** being our app name

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the plugin version does not matter for now.

I hope you'd pay your attention to the following statement:

> Make sure you initialize Intercom correctly.

### [Step 2 - Initialize Intercom](https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/cordova-phonegap-installation#section-step-2-initialize-intercom)

First, you'll need to get your Intercom app ID and iOS/Android API key. To find these, just select the 'Intercom for iOS' or 'Intercom for Android' option in Settings > Installation > iOS / Android.

[image]

Then initialize Intercom by importing Intercom and adding the following to your `config.xml`:

```xml
<preference name="intercom-app-id" value="your_app_id"/>
<preference name="intercom-ios-api-key" value="ios_sdk-..."/>
<preference name="intercom-android-api-key" value="android_sdk-..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I had to open up xcode's workspace file rather then the proj to include the pods.